# Lines Abstract Keyword

Tags: abstract, keywords

im super new in Latex. I just read some basic stuff. And i have this :

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\title{Hunky panpsychism}
\author{}
\date{\today}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\renewenvironment{abstract}{%
\noindent\bfseries\abstractname:\normalfont}{}
\begin{abstract}
hgfhfhgfhfhgf gfghfhfh hhgfhgfhgfh.\\
{\bf Keywords:} Panpsychism, Micropsychism, Cosmopsychism, Gunky worlds, Junky worlds, Hunky worlds, Metaphysical infinitism, Metaphysical foundationalism Non-well-founded.
\end{abstract}
\section{Introduction}
Now that we have written our abstract, we can begin writing our first paragraph.\footnote{STRAWSON}
\end{document}
```

I need one line above the abstract and other line below the abstract and keyword. The width of lines should be equal to the width of abstract. The lines should not be larger than the width of the abstract and keywords.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my understanding of your post, you need lines above for the head `Abstract` and `Keywords` and the line should not exceed both the heads, if my understanding is correct, then the below tags may help you:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\newbox\absbox
\setbox\absbox=\hbox{\bfseries\abstractname:}%

\renewcommand\abstractname{\noindent\rule{\wd\absbox}{0.25pt}\\Abstract}

\newbox\keywbox
\setbox\keywbox=\hbox{\bfseries Keywords:}%

\newcommand\keywords{%
\noindent\rule{\wd\keywbox}{0.25pt}\\\textbf{Keywords:}\ }

\title{Hunky panpsychism}
\author{}
\date{\today}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\renewenvironment{abstract}{%
\noindent\bfseries\abstractname:\normalfont}{}
\begin{abstract}
hgfhfhgfhfhgf gfghfhfh hhgfhgfhgfh.\\
\keywords Panpsychism, Micropsychism, Cosmopsychism, Gunky worlds, Junky worlds, Hunky worlds, Metaphysical infinitism, Metaphysical foundationalism Non-well-founded.
\end{abstract}
\section{Introduction}
Now that we have written our abstract, we can begin writing our first paragraph.\footnote{STRAWSON}
\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Its very usefull. But what i really want is putting the line above the keywords below it. The first line above the abstract its ok.

So, first line above abstract. Second line below keywords.

Again thanks. And sorry for my english.